# Error vuejs usando component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy usando componentes de vuejs, tengo un `template` llamado `slider` y dentro un `v-for` que recorre un arreglo de noticias.

Pero me da el siguiente error:

[image: captura]

Este es el archivo app.js

```
Vue.component('slider', {

    template: ` 
    <div>   
        <div v-for="noticia in arrayNoticias" class="item-slider" style="background:url('https://i.imgur.com/Ort6NMU.jpg');">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div  class="info-slider">
                            <h1> {{ title.rendered }} </h1>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-iw outline">Leer más <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
});


let app = new Vue({
    el: '#layout',
    data() {
        return {
            arrayNoticias: [],
            loading: true,
            errored: false
        }
    },
    methods : {
        listarNoticias(){
            axios.get('/posts')
            .then(response => {
                this.arrayNoticias = response.data
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                this.errored = true
            }).finally(() => this.loading = false)
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.listarNoticias();
    },
});
```

index.php

`<div id="layout">  <slider ></slider> </div>`

Estos son los CDN que estoy usando

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js
https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js

y para hacer la referencia al archivo app.js
assets/js/app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas ocupando `arrayNoticias` en tu componente global, pero ese misma **propiedad** solo existe dentro de la instancia de VueJS, entonces lo que puedes hacer es pasarlo como una prop en el componente para poder utilizarla de este modo:

```
Vue.component('slider', {
    props: ['arrayNoticias'],
    template: ` 
    <div>   
        <div v-for="noticia in arrayNoticias" class="item-slider" style="background:url('https://i.imgur.com/Ort6NMU.jpg');">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div  class="info-slider">
                            <h1> {{ title.rendered }} </h1>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-iw outline">Leer más <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
});
```

Ahora en tu vista para invocar al componente quedaría así:

```
<slider :arrayNoticias="arrayNoticias"></slider>
```

Comment: Ya no me aparece el error, pero dentro en el <Slider> me aparece como arrayNoticias:undefined en el <Root> si me aparece la data.

Comment: @LuisHernandez revisa si con lo que coloqué al final te ayuda

Comment: me aparece lo siguiente: [Vue tip]: Prop "arraynoticias" is passed to component <Anonymous>, but the declared prop name is "arrayNoticias". Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and camelCased props need to use their kebab-case equivalents when using in-DOM templates. You should probably use "array-noticias" instead of "arrayNoticias".

Comment: ummm que raro no se por que te aparece ese aviso, no veo que escribas con minúsculas, de todos modos déjame revisar @LuisHernandez

Comment: Seguro que lo escribiste en mayúsculas? @LuisHernandez como camel case?

Comment: Listo amigo, lo puse todo en minúsculas y FUNCIONO! Muchas gracias!